# SQL Server database stuck in restoring state after BACKUP LOG WITH NORECOVERY

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

Used SQL Server Management Studio to restore a database but "Take tail-log backup with NORECOVERY" was checked and user didn't have permission to RESTORE database.

So T-SQL commands executed in this order (generated in SQL Server Management Studio):

```
BACKUP LOG [database] 
TO DISK = N'...DatabaseBackup_2016-08-28_14-07-05.bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
     NAME = N'...DatabaseBackup_2016-08-28_14-07-05', NOSKIP, NOREWIND,
     NOUNLOAD,  NORECOVERY, STATS = 5
```

Executed OK

```
RESTORE DATABASE [database] 
FROM DISK = N'....database.bak' 
WITH FILE = 1.....
```

Failed (User doesn't have right for RESTORE)

```
RESTORE DATABASE <database> WITH RECOVERY
```

doesn't work because of permission

So the question is how to release database from restoring state and how did the server allow me to set database into restoring state without permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions for BACKUP and RESTORE operations are different.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx

, so the user may have permissions to backup the log and put it into restoring mode, but may not have permissions to restore the database.

Modify the user permissions, it should work.